# Plot a smooth curve of CDF

Tags: python

I am trying to plot the CDF of two df. I am using the following code

```
plt.hist([df['A'], df['B']], 1000, density=True, histtype='step', cumulative=True, label='Empirical')
```

plt.show()

and I get this graph:

[image]

This graph seems correct, however, I would like to get it without the vertical 90 degrees line at the end, also how can I cut the y-axis at 1?

Thanks

Comment: maybe try `plt.hist([df['A'][0:-2], df['B'][0:-2]], 1000, density=True, histtype='step', cumulative=True, label='Empirical')`?

Comment: I tried but it dit not change anything on the graph

Comment: okay, then maybe we need at least the last portion of the columns you try to plot

Comment: `pyplot.hist` is accustomed to drawing filled contours (`Patch` objects) so your "line" is actually an *outline* of a shape (which must be a closed contour). What you want is a line object from something like `pyplot.plot`

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the path dropping to zero at the end is as simple as not using `pyplot.hist`. I would instead use `numpy.histogram` and generate my own CDF points to feed into a simple line plot with `pyplot.plot`:

```
#generate bins and bin edges
A, Aedges = np.histogram(df['A'], bins = 1000)
B, Bedges = np.histogram(df['B'], bins = 1000)
#cumsum and normalize to get cdf rather than pdf
A = np.cumsum(A)
A /= A[-1]
B = np.cumsum(B)
B /= B[-1]
#convert bin edges to bin centers
Acenters = (Aedges[:-1]+Aedges[1:])/2
Bcenters = (Bedges[:-1]+Bedges[1:])/2
#plot a simple line plot instead of a histogram
plt.plot(A, Acenters)
plt.plot(B, Bcenters)
```

If you want to customize the spines / box around the plot: here's an example copied from a [matplotlib cheat sheet](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/michael.blaschek/openfiles/Matplotlib%20Notes.pdf) I keep around:

#### Hiding the top and right spines

```
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 800)
y = np.sin(x)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
ax.plot(x, y, label='Sine', color='red')
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('#e5e5e5')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['left'].set_position(
('outward',10))
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(
('outward',10))
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
# do the ax.grid() after setting ticks
ax.grid(b=True, which='both',
color='white', linestyle='-',
linewidth=1.5)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.legend(loc='best', frameon=False)
fig.savefig('filename.png', dpi=125)
```

[image]

If you're using `pyplot` instead of a dedicated figure / axes combo, you can get `ax` from `plt` using `plt.gca()`.